# How to add default value for attribute of configurable product

Tags: magento2

My configurable product have 2 attributes (size, color).
When customer visit product detail page, I want to set default value (first value) for size and color.

Example:
Product1: size(X,M, L), color (RED, BLUE, WHITE).

Customer access to product detail page -> Size M and color RED are selected.

Comment: You can achieve using swatch.js file

Answer (score 2):

`swatch-renderer.js` is responsible for swatches in configurable product.

You have to override `swatch-renderer.js` file to achieve your things.

For override `swatch-renderer.js` follow below step.

1. Add `requirejs-config.js` file with given below path.

   > app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

   `var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Namespace_ModuleName/js/swatch-renderer': true
            }
        }
    }
   };`
2. Add `swatch-renderer.js file with given below path.

   > app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

   define([
       'jquery',
       'mage/url'
   ], function ($, url) {
       'use strict';

   ```
   return function (widget) {
       $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', widget, {

           // Add your custom logic

       });
       return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;
   }
   });
   </script>
   ```

I hope it helps!